# Doxygen make pdflatex fail on Debian VM

Tags: makefile, debian, doxygen, pdflatex

I installed Doxygen on a Debian VM on Virtualbox, hosted by a Windows 10 pc. It runs smoothly as creates all the basic documentations, but when I enter into a latex documentation directory and try to run `make` it gives me the following bash report (roughly translated from italian):

```
rm -f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf
pdflatex refman
make: pdflatex: command not found
Makefile:8: instruction set for target "refman.pdf" failed
make: *** [refman.pdf] Error 127
```

I searched for this error but I couldn't find anything about. Both the doxyfile and the latex makefile aren't modifed.

Comment: looks like pdflatex cannot be found. Did you install e.g. Tex Live? What happens when you just give the command pdflatex --version?

Comment: Yes, I installed it trying to solve this error. Oddly bash doesn't recognise `pdflatex --version` too

Comment: Looks the directory where pdflatex is installed is not added to your path. Check where you can find pdflatex and check with a simple tex document if you can create a pdf document of it, it might be that other, debian specific, setting have to be made.

Comment: Looks like the problem was right in path, thanks! Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results form generating with doxygen generated Makefile indicates that the pdflatex cannot be found.

Problem appears to be that the installation of TexLive didn't add the directory with e.g. pdflatex to the path.